# How to compute the expectation of the Moorse-Penrose pseudoinverse of the sum of non-independent Wishart distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions

There are $T+n-1$ random vectors $\{\mathbf{x}_{1},\mathbf{x}_{2},\dots,\mathbf{x}_{n},\dots,\mathbf{x}_{T+n-1}\}$, where $\mathbf{x}_{i}  \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0, \boldsymbol{I}_{p}\right)$ , $\boldsymbol{I}_{p} $ is a $p\times p$ unit matrix, and $ \mathbf{x}_{i}\in \mathbb{R}^{p}$ for $i\in\{1,2,\dots,T+n-1 \}$.

Let $\mathbf{X}_{1}=[\mathbf{x}_{1}\; \mathbf{x}_{2}\; \cdots\; \mathbf{x}_{n}]$, $\mathbf{X}_{2}=[\mathbf{x}_{2}\; \mathbf{x}_{3}\; \cdots\; \mathbf{x}_{n+1}]$, $\dots$, $\mathbf{X}_{T}=[\mathbf{x}_{1}\; \mathbf{x}_{2}\; \cdots\  \mathbf{x}_{T+n-1}]\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times n}$, we can know quickly that $\mathbf{X}_{j}^{\top}\mathbf{X}_{j}$ is a [Wishart distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_distribution), which is denoted by $\mathcal{W}(I_{n},p)$, where $\boldsymbol{I}_{n} $ is a $n\times n$ unit matrix and $p$ is the number of degrees of freedom, and $\left(\mathbf{X}_{j}^{\top}\mathbf{X}_{j}\right)^{\dagger}$ is an [Inverse-Wishart distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-Wishart_distribution#cite_ref-MardiaK1979Multivariate_4-0), which is denoted by $\mathcal{W}^{-1}(I_{n},p)$, where $\dagger$ denotes Moorse-Penrose Pseudoinverse, for $j\in\{1,2,\dots,T\}$. We can easily know that the expectation of $\left(\mathbf{X}_{j}^{\top}\mathbf{X}_{j}\right)^{\dagger}$ is $\frac{\mathbf{I}_{n}}{p-n-1}$ for $p>n+1$.

However,how to compute the expectation of $\left(\sum_{j=1}^{T}\mathbf{X}_{j}^{\top}\mathbf{X}_{j}\right)^{\dagger}$? Are the **upper** and **lower** bound of the expectation of $\left(\sum_{j=1}^{T}\mathbf{X}_{j}^{\top}\mathbf{X}_{j}\right)^{\dagger}$ connected with the expectation of $\left(\mathbf{X}_{j}^{\top}\mathbf{X}_{j}\right)^{\dagger}$?

Comment: $(X^{\intercal}X)^{+}=X^{+}(X^{+})^{\intercal}$

Comment: @xXACEXx What is your meaning?